# Can't run a program through a link?

Tags: windows, command-line, path, hardlink

I'm working on a Windows 8.1 machine, fully patched, except for the Get Windows X malware. I have Android's SDK installed at `C:\android-sdk`, but its not on-path. I'm trying to avoid putting 2 SDK directories and 1 NDK directory on-path since it includes a lot of extra binaries.

I can navigate to `C:\android-sdk\platform-tools` and then execute `adb.exe`.

I can create a shortcut to `adb.exe` called `adb.exe.lnk` and place it in `C:\Windows`. The shortcut includes ***Start in***, so the DLLs used by `adb.exe` are on path. The shortcut can execute `adb.exe`.

However, Windows can't seem to run `adb.exe.lnk` from the command line, so I created a hard link to the shortcut:

```
C:\Windows>mklink /H adb.exe C:\Windows\adb.exe.lnk
Hardlink created for adb.exe <<===>> C:\Windows\adb.exe.lnk
```

Now, when I run `adb.exe` from the command line I get:

> The program or feature "\??\C:\Windows\adb.exe" cannot start
>   or run due to incompatibity with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please
>   contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible
>   version is available.

And:

[image]

I also tried using Windows Compatibility from the properties tab, but it produced the same result. Failed attempts include Windows XP and Windows XP SP3.

Why does Windows claim `adb.exe` is a 16-bit application?

What can I do to create a shortcut on-path that Windows can successfully execute?

---

I can't create a direct hard link to `C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe` because it lacks path information. Attempting to execute it results in an error *"The program can't start..."* due to missing DLLs. That's why I needed the intermediate `adb.exe.lnk`.

---

Finally, many questions surrounding the *"The program or feature \??\C:\Windows... cannot start or run"* message seem to indicate malware or a corrupt registry. For example, [Windows 7 Explorer.exe incompatibility](https://superuser.com/q/376535). I don't believe either applies here.

Comment: Just a Thought but don you have to use " around .lnk example.  "C:\Windows>mklink /H adb.exe" "C:\Windows\adb.exe.lnk"  Cant remember if you need to just do it around the whole thing or Separate it like i did in the example give it a shot?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 64bits version of Windows, you won't be able to launch 16bits programs.

Each architecture version of Windows supports only it's own architecture (obvious) and the previous one.

For exemple :
A 64bits Windows can launch 32 and 64 bits softwares.
A 32bits Windows can launch 16 and 32 bits softwares.

And the comptibility mode of Windows respects this principle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mklink` to create a symbolic (or hard) link directly to `C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe`.

What you've done here is make a hard link to an Explorer shortcut. This is the same result you'd get if you just renamed the shortcut with a `.exe` extension.

The `mklink` command creates links at the NTFS file system layer. When you access an NTFS symbolic link, the Windows NTFS driver is the thing that resolves it. So it works for any program that accesses the file system.

Shortcuts (`.lnk` files) are functionally similar to symbolic links, but implemented in the shell rather than in the file system. When you double-click a shortcut in Explorer, it is Explorer itself that resolves the shortcut. Theoretically other programs could handle them too, but to my knowledge the file format isn't officially documented.

In particular, the Windows PE loader (the part of the kernel that parses `.exe` and `.dll` files and puts them in RAM to be executed) can't parse `.lnk` files, which are *not* valid executables.